# python - requests, using data parametres with same name

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

So, I'm using python request to POST data to an API, this API allows me to check more users at the same time by using the same data param,
example: if I want to check j@mail.com & x@gmail.com, if I used GET, (but I wanna use POST because I wanna check a lot of mails with one request) I'd have to query this url: htttps://website.com/API?email=j@mail.com&email=x@mail.com.
How do I change my dict (v) in order to make this possible?

This is the code I've written:

```
def query(rurl, data):
    r =  requests.post(rurl, data = data).json()
    print (r)

def main():
    v = {
        'apikey': apikey,
        'email': username,
        'password': password,

       }
     query('https://website.com/API', v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you give a `list` object as your value in `v` for a certain key, it produces multiple parameters of the same name. For example:

```
v = { ...
     "email": ["j@mail.com", "x@mail.com"],
      ... }
```

This should work with either `GET` or `POST` requests.

To incorporate this into your existing code:

```
def query(rurl, data):
    r =  requests.post(rurl, data = data).json()
    print (r)

def main():
    v = {
        'apikey': apikey,
        'email': [username1, username2],
        'password': password,

       }
     query('https://website.com/API', v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Works, but I have one more question: if the API required me to POST email&pass and then email&pass again, would it  be possible to post them in this order using the dictionary?

Comment: If you want to order the items, use a tuple of tuples instead of a dictionary, like this: `(("apikey", ...), ("email", ...), ("pass", ...), ("email", ...), ("pass", ...))`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

```
def query(rurl, data):
    r =  requests.post(rurl, params = data)
    print (r)

v = { ...
 "email": ["j@mail.com", "x@mail.com"],
  ... }
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing. It doesn't help anyone when you post your code with no explanation.